# Shortcuts created with the Advertise property ignore VisualElementsManifest customizations (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, wix

When publishing a shortcut using the WiX 'Advertise' option, the end result produces a Start Menu shortcut that ignores my application's [VisualElementsManifest.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx).

```
<Shortcut ... Advertise="yes" />
```

When I remove the tag, Windows 8 will then process/render my application shortcut with the proper customizations from the VisualElementsManifest file.

```
  <VisualElements BackgroundColor="#333333"
                  ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo="on"
                  ForegroundText="light"
                  />
```

When I choose not to use the advertise feature, the 'Target' area of my shortcut is populated with the full location to the executable. When I don't use the advertise feature, the 'Target' property of the shortcut is blank and disabled. Obviously two different shortcut types and behaviors are created.

My question is this; is it possible to use the 'Advertise' feature and have the VisualElementsManifest applied? Do I need to place the file in a different location or name it differently?